# Отправка формы с помощью ajax, форма при этом динамически создается на сайте. native JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем доброго дня.
Не получается у меня реализовать отправку формы через js, форма создается при этом при клике на кнопку. И получается что я получаю `form = null`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  wr = document.getElementById("wrap");
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.id = "myform";
    form.innerHTML = "<input placeholder='Наименование' name='title'><input placeholder='Цена' name='price'><input type='submit' value='Добавить'>";
    wr.appendChild(form);
  }, false);


});

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  function sendData() {
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var FD = new FormData(form);

    xhr.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
      alert(event.target.responseText);
    });

    xhr.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
      alert('Oops! Something went wrong.');
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "/add");

    xhr.send(FD);
  }

  var form = document.getElementById("myform");
  console.log(form);

  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit");
    sendData();
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">CREATE form</button>
<div id="wrap">
  <div>
```

как решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что `load` срабатывает раньше, чем у вас создается форма по клику на кнопку.

Comment: а как сделать чтобы я начал слушать форму после ее создания? Или попробовать завернуть ее в функцию, и запуская функцию после создания формы?

Comment: Написать код, отвечающий за прослушивания события `submit`, после успешного создания формы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  wr = document.getElementById('wrap');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var form = document.createElement("FORM");
    form.id = 'myform';
    form.innerHTML = '<input placeholder="Наименование" name="title"><input placeholder="Цена" name="price"><input type="submit" value="Добавить">';
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('submit');
      sendData(this);
    });
    wr.appendChild(form);
  }, false);

  function sendData(form) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var FD = new FormData(form);

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
      alert(event.target.responseText);
    });

    xhr.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
      alert('Oops! Something went wrong.');
    });

    xhr.open('POST', '/add');

    xhr.send(FD);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">CREATE form</button>
<div id="wrap">
  <div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, как раз до этого сам дошел, а тут вы ответили.